# Change the table name of queue table of customer(my_customer_table) to my custom in quickbook web connector library php

Tags: quickbooks

I am working on php quickbook web connector SDK and i want to change the table name for the queue of customers. Right now it's my_customer_table but now i want to replace it with my own table. Please suggest me changes so i can try.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post your code. How can we help you if you don't show us your code?

Comment: I am using the library of consolibyte for connecting webconnector with my php files. but it uses my_customer_table for managing the call.